# Consumer "received" event not firing

Tags: c#, rabbitmq

I'm trying to set up a subscription to a RabbitMQ queue and pass it a custom event handler.
So I have a class called `RabbitMQClient` which contains the following method:

```
public void Subscribe(string queueName, EventHandler<BasicDeliverEventArgs> receivedHandler)
{
    using (var connection = factory.CreateConnection())
    {
        using (var channel = connection.CreateModel())
        {
            channel.QueueDeclare(
                queue: queueName,
                durable: false,
                exclusive: false,
                autoDelete: false,
                arguments: null
            );

            var consumer = new EventingBasicConsumer(channel);

            consumer.Received += receivedHandler;

            channel.BasicConsume(
                queue: queueName,
                autoAck: false,
                consumer: consumer
            );
        }
    }
}
```

I'm using dependency injection, so I have a `RabbitMQClient` (singleton) interface for it.

In my consuming class, I have this method which I want to act as the `EventHandler`

```
public void Consumer_Received(object sender, BasicDeliverEventArgs e)
{
    var message = e.Body.FromByteArray<ProgressQueueMessage>();
}
```

And I'm trying to subscribe to the queue like this:

```
rabbitMQClient.Subscribe(Consts.RabbitMQ.ProgressQueue, Consumer_Received);
```

I can see that the queue starts to get messages, but the `Consumer_Received` method is not firing.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

"Using" calls dispose on your connection and your event wont be triggered. Just remove your "using" block from the code so that it doesn't close the connection.

```
var connection = factory.CreateConnection();

var channel = connection.CreateModel();

channel.QueueDeclare(
    queue: queueName,
    durable: false,
    exclusive: false,
    autoDelete: false,
    arguments: null);

var consumer = new EventingBasicConsumer(channel);

consumer.Received += receivedHandler;

channel.BasicConsume(
    queue: queueName,
    autoAck: false,
    consumer: consumer);
```

Comment: OP said the class is a singleton. I guess it would be a good idea to keep a static List of channels, then.

Comment: I can't believe I didn't see that... This is such a beginners mistake. I think I'll delete this question because it is so obvious...

Comment: @vhr, Still, It's embarrassing :-)

Comment: @LiranFriedman Not really. That's exactly why we have "review", too. If you write something, you can read it 1000 times and you don't see an obvious mistake. Have someone else read it and he will catch it ... We are all human after all.

Comment: @Fildor Well said

Comment: perfect! i had the same problem

Comment: Fun part, their official documentation / tutorial shows putting both inside a using block.

Comment: @LiranFriedman I am new to C#, but I am confused that if the function already return, why the connection or the channel or the consumer.Receive event still there! Or actually they all be register into the another thread hold by Rabbitmq client library. I can't find the answer in the document. Can you help it? Thanks very much.

Comment: save my day !  @user1689716  official document put "using " in the top block of the application, not in a "scope"(in a method) block, so , the rabbitmq instances(factory,model,...) will not disposed.